# Is it possible to recover a pipenv virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv

I somehow changed the virtual environment I was using with a Django project when making changes to Pycharm settings. Now my project is using Python 3.8 when it had been using 3.9 earlier and an app I had installed via `pip` is no longer recognized.

I get the following warning when entering the shell in the terminal:

```
Warning: Your Pipfile requires python_version 3.9,
but you are using 3.8.2 (/Users/w/.local/share/v/o/bin/python).

$ pipenv --rm and rebuilding the virtual environment may resolve the issue.
$ pipenv check will surely fail.
```

Is there a way to recover the previous virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have not deleted the environment, it should still be saved and ready to be selected from the python interpreter selector.

Press Ctrl+Alt+S to open the project Settings/Preferences and go to Project  | Python Interpreter. The previously added (virtual) environments should be there.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Even though I didn't intentionally delete the environment it appears to be gone. If I go to Users/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/projectname-buY8b9MQ/lib/python3.9 there is no longer a python 3.9 version. I only see 3.8. 

I had not originally started the project in Pycharm. Somehow changing some settings in Pycharm after I opened the project there appears to have deleted the original environment.

Comment: There is no virtual environment in the trash, however. It appears to have been overwritten.

Comment: That's super weird. At least you now know what happened. Good luck!